# Java datastore client throws "Not implemented" at runAggregation

Tags: java, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, jvm, google-cloud-datastore

I am trying new [feature count](https://github.com/googleapis/java-datastore/commit/8c22e61f8a0307a59301259f83a16c8324fa1b6f#diff-039f087fc36dbed8761c6dfc3e757626fd9d7902ee96e9b7344832b93dc533fd) with an aggregate query, but "runAggregation" from Datastore interface has implemented

```
throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not implemented.");
```

even thought DatastoreImpl implements.

This is how my code is looking, basically I copied from examples code/java doc:

```
val selectAllQuery = Query.newEntityQueryBuilder().setKind(entityName).build()
val aggregationQuery: AggregationQuery =
    Query.newAggregationQueryBuilder().addAggregation(count().`as`("total_count")).over(selectAllQuery).build()


val aggregationResults =
    datastore.runAggregation(aggregationQuery).forEach {
        println(it)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, the DatastoreReader interface has a default implementation that throws an `UnsupportedOperationException`. You can see this on [GitHub](https://github.com/googleapis/java-datastore/blob/a45940880d18218f58dc68252a9730e63139093a/google-cloud-datastore/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/datastore/DatastoreReader.java#L64).

However, this is not a problem, because the actual `DatastoreReader` instance you will be using after calling `DatastoreOptions.getDefaultInstance().service` overrides this default implementation. The concrete type of this instance is [`DatastoreImpl`](https://github.com/googleapis/java-datastore/blob/main/google-cloud-datastore/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/datastore/DatastoreImpl.java), and you can also see the actual implementation of the overridden `runAggregation` method on [GitHub](https://github.com/googleapis/java-datastore/blob/a45940880d18218f58dc68252a9730e63139093a/google-cloud-datastore/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/datastore/DatastoreImpl.java#L202).

Comment: Thanks for you response. Yes, DatastoreImpl is the instance for DatastoreReader at runtime. Still in my Kotlin example it fails with the exception that is implemented in the interface. At compilation time, I can not change Datastore type to DatastoreImpl, it is a private class.

Comment: Can you check what type the instance returned from `DatastoreOptions.getDefaultInstance().service` has?

Comment: It is DatastoreImpl at runtime.

Comment: Then it should not throw this exception. Can you add the full stack trace from the exception in your question?

Comment: I test it directly in Gcloud, and I do not get the same error. It might be due to I am using local data store emulator when testing locally.

Comment: Yes, then the problem is in the emulator, and it isn't coming from `DatastoreImpl`.